# Can't get a Static Web Project to be available in Servers 'Add and Remove' in SpringSource Tool Suite

Tags: eclipse, static, springsource

I am trying to add a Static Web Site to my localhost server.  But, I can't seem to get it to show up as a resource for me to add it to my server as a configured resource.

In the Eclipse project navigator, I select File-->New-->Project-->Web-->Static Web Project, I type in project 'XYZ', and click finish.  Then, when I go to my servers view and click the localhost server, and click 'Add and Remove', my new project XYZ doesn't show up for me to select.

If I do a File-->New-->Project-->SpringSource Tool Suite-->Spring Template Project-->Spring MVC project, then STS creates the project and it shows up in the 'Add and Remove' window of the localhost server.

This little XYZ is a super simple site of one page and three graphics.  I don't particularly want to have all the muss and fuss the fully dynamic Spring app involves.

But maybe I have to.

Thanks